# ZeroMQ Broadcast with Proxy losing messages

Tags: c#, .net, zeromq

I am doing some performance tests on ZeroMQ in order to compare it with others like RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ.

In my broadcast tests and to avoid "The Dynamic Discovery Problem" as referred by ZeroMQ documentation I have used a proxy. In my scenario, I am using 50 concurrent publishers each one sending 500 messages with 1ms delay between sends. Each message is then read by 50 subscribers. And as I said I am losing messages, each of the subscribers should receive a total of 25000 messages and they are each receiving between 5000 and 10000 messages only.

I am using Windows and C# .Net client clrzmq4 (4.1.0.31).

I have already tried some solutions that I found on other posts:

- I have set linger to TimeSpan.MaxValue
- I have set ReceiveHighWatermark to 0 (as it is presented as infinite, but I have tried also Int32.MaxValue)
- I have set checked for slow start receivers, I made receivers start some seconds before publishers
- I had to make sure that no garbage collection is made to the socket instances (linger should do it but to make sure)
- I have a similar scenario (with similar logic) using NetMQ and it works fine. The other scenario does not use security though and this one does (and that's also the reason why I use clrzmq in this one because I need client authentication with certificates that is not yet possible on NetMQ).

EDIT:

```
public class MCVEPublisher
{
    public void publish(int numberOfMessages)
    {
        string topic = "TopicA";

        ZContext ZContext = ZContext.Create();
        ZSocket publisher = new ZSocket(ZContext, ZSocketType.PUB);

        //Security
        // Create or load certificates
        ZCert serverCert = Main.GetOrCreateCert("publisher");
        var actor = new ZActor(ZContext, ZAuth.Action, null);
        actor.Start();
        // send CURVE settings to ZAuth
        actor.Frontend.Send(new ZFrame("VERBOSE"));
        actor.Frontend.Send(new ZMessage(new List<ZFrame>()
            { new ZFrame("ALLOW"), new ZFrame("127.0.0.1") }));
        actor.Frontend.Send(new ZMessage(new List<ZFrame>()
            { new ZFrame("CURVE"), new ZFrame(".curve") }));
        publisher.CurvePublicKey = serverCert.PublicKey;
        publisher.CurveSecretKey = serverCert.SecretKey;
        publisher.CurveServer = true;


        publisher.Linger = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        publisher.ReceiveHighWatermark = Int32.MaxValue;
        publisher.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5678");
        Thread.Sleep(3500);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMessages; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            var update = $"{topic} {"message"}";
            using (var updateFrame = new ZFrame(update))
            {
                publisher.Send(updateFrame);
            }

        }

        //just to make sure it does not end instantly
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        //just to make sure publisher is not garbage collected
        ulong Affinity = publisher.Affinity;
    }
}

public class MCVESubscriber
{
    private ZSocket subscriber;
    private List<string> prints = new List<string>();

    public void read()
    {
        string topic = "TopicA";

        var context = new ZContext();
        subscriber = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.SUB);

        //Security
        ZCert serverCert = Main.GetOrCreateCert("xpub");
        ZCert clientCert = Main.GetOrCreateCert("subscriber");
        subscriber.CurvePublicKey = clientCert.PublicKey;
        subscriber.CurveSecretKey = clientCert.SecretKey;
        subscriber.CurveServer = true;
        subscriber.CurveServerKey = serverCert.PublicKey;

        subscriber.Linger = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        subscriber.ReceiveHighWatermark = Int32.MaxValue;

        // Connect
        subscriber.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:1234");
        subscriber.Subscribe(topic);
        while (true)
        {
            using (var replyFrame = subscriber.ReceiveFrame())
            {
                string messageReceived = replyFrame.ReadString();
                messageReceived = Convert.ToString(messageReceived.Split(' ')[1]);
                prints.Add(messageReceived);
            }
        }
    }

    public void PrintMessages()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("printing " + prints.Count);
    }

}

public class Main
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        broadcast(500, 50, 50, 30000);
    }

    public static void broadcast(int numberOfMessages, int numberOfPublishers, int numberOfSubscribers, int timeOfRun)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            using (var context = new ZContext())
            using (var xsubSocket = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.XSUB))
            using (var xpubSocket = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.XPUB))
            {
                //Security
                ZCert serverCert = GetOrCreateCert("publisher");
                ZCert clientCert = GetOrCreateCert("xsub");
                xsubSocket.CurvePublicKey = clientCert.PublicKey;
                xsubSocket.CurveSecretKey = clientCert.SecretKey;
                xsubSocket.CurveServer = true;
                xsubSocket.CurveServerKey = serverCert.PublicKey;

                xsubSocket.Linger = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
                xsubSocket.ReceiveHighWatermark = Int32.MaxValue;
                xsubSocket.Bind("tcp://*:5678");


                //Security
                serverCert = GetOrCreateCert("xpub");
                var actor = new ZActor(ZAuth.Action0, null);
                actor.Start();
                // send CURVE settings to ZAuth
                actor.Frontend.Send(new ZFrame("VERBOSE"));
                actor.Frontend.Send(new ZMessage(new List<ZFrame>()
                    { new ZFrame("ALLOW"), new ZFrame("127.0.0.1") }));
                actor.Frontend.Send(new ZMessage(new List<ZFrame>()
                    { new ZFrame("CURVE"), new ZFrame(".curve") }));
                xpubSocket.CurvePublicKey = serverCert.PublicKey;
                xpubSocket.CurveSecretKey = serverCert.SecretKey;
                xpubSocket.CurveServer = true;

                xpubSocket.Linger = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
                xpubSocket.ReceiveHighWatermark = Int32.MaxValue;
                xpubSocket.Bind("tcp://*:1234");


                using (var subscription = ZFrame.Create(1))
                {
                    subscription.Write(new byte[] { 0x1 }, 0, 1);
                    xpubSocket.Send(subscription);
                }


                Console.WriteLine("Intermediary started, and waiting for messages");
                // proxy messages between frontend / backend
                ZContext.Proxy(xsubSocket, xpubSocket);
                Console.WriteLine("end of proxy");


                //just to make sure it does not end instantly
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
                //just to make sure xpubSocket and xsubSocket are not garbage collected
                ulong Affinity = xpubSocket.Affinity;
                int ReceiveHighWatermark = xsubSocket.ReceiveHighWatermark;

            }
        }).Start();

        Thread.Sleep(5000); //to make sure proxy started
        List<MCVESubscriber> Subscribers = new List<MCVESubscriber>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSubscribers; i++)
        {
            MCVESubscriber ZeroMqSubscriber = new MCVESubscriber();
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                ZeroMqSubscriber.read();
            }).Start();
            Subscribers.Add(ZeroMqSubscriber);
        }


        Thread.Sleep(10000);//to make sure all subscribers started
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPublishers; i++)
        {
            MCVEPublisher ZeroMqPublisherBroadcast = new MCVEPublisher();
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                ZeroMqPublisherBroadcast.publish(numberOfMessages);
            }).Start();
        }

        Thread.Sleep(timeOfRun);
        foreach (MCVESubscriber Subscriber in Subscribers)
        {
            Subscriber.PrintMessages();
        }
    }

    public static ZCert GetOrCreateCert(string name, string curvpath = ".curve")
    {
        ZCert cert;
        string keyfile = Path.Combine(curvpath, name + ".pub");
        if (!File.Exists(keyfile))
        {
            cert = new ZCert();
            Directory.CreateDirectory(curvpath);
            cert.SetMeta("name", name);
            cert.Save(keyfile);
        }
        else
        {
            cert = ZCert.Load(keyfile);
        }

        return cert;
    }
}
```

This code also produces the expected number of messages when security is disabled, but when turned on it doesn't.

Does someone know another thing to check? Or has it happened to anyone before?

Thanks

Comment: Great to have mentioned the version. Yet, **where are all the MCVE-code details** to see and be able to reproduce the test and answer your question?

Comment: True...I will edit the post and add it

Comment: Better, yet still not-a-reproducible MCVE code - missing declarations, missing to see, how the MCVE spawns "***50 concurrent publishers each one sending 500 messages with 1ms delay between sends. ***" + "***50 subscribers***" + theirs topic setup / subscription.

Comment: @user3666197 I edited it. Now you should be able to test it, this exact code does not work on my computer. As I have also pointed with the last edit, this code works when security is not enabled (just by commenting the "//Security" blocks)

Comment: The problem was solved by setting also SendHighWatermark to a high value (I missed that property) and by increasing context input-output number of threads (encryption is heavy, in my case I have set it to 4 threads)